# Can Peterson algorithm get in deadlock?

Tags: algorithm, deadlock, critical-section

[image: peterson algorithm]

So let suppose we have two processes (0 and 1).
0 calls the enter_region. 
It sets the  `interested[0]= TRUE`
The execution gets halted.

Now the process 1 comes.
`interested[1] = TRUE`
`turn = 1`
In the while loop the conditions are met, so it enter the critical section.

Execution gets back to 0.
`turn = 0` 
The while loop condition also true, so neither 0 can enter the critical section, which results in deadlock.

Is it right? Or the example algorithm contains error somewhere?

The picture comes from: tanenbaum operating systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The while loop condition also true, so neither 0 can enter the critical section, which results in deadlock.
>
> Is it right?

No, because thread `1` setting `turn` to `1` causes thread `0` to fall out of the loop when it gets scheduled.

Comment: Ohh, really. I see it now. Thanks